# How to define elements in matrix in Java, where in every next row elements increase for some value?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

For example I want to make this kind of matrix:

```
1  1  1  1  1  1
4  4  4  4  4  4
9  9  9  9  9  9
16 16 16 16 16 16 
25 25 25 25 25 25 
36 36 36 36 36 36
49 49 49 49 49 49
```

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int matrix[][] = new int[6][8];

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {

                matrix[i][j] = i + 1 ;
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you are experiencing with your current code?

Comment: You're putting the "row-number-plus-one" in each element; what you want is the "row-number-plus-one" **squared** (i.e, "row-number-plus-one" times "row-number-plus-one")

Comment: I can't figure out correct algorithm. Whatever i try, i can't get matrix witch i want. Whatever i try i can't get current solution.. I think i got every possible solution except that one which i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, *each element in your result matrix is square of the row number*.

**Eg.**

```
Row 1 -> Numbers 1
Row 2 -> Numbers 4
Row 3 -> Numbers 9
...
Row 7 -> Numbers 49

and so on...
```

So you don't need the previous numbers to calculate the new ones.

A **simple tweak** in your existing code, while **populating the matrix**, would work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = (int) Math.pow(i + 1, 2);
    }
}
```

And **print the matrix** using :

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Also, `for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++)` should be `for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)`

Comment: @ShanuGupta thank you for your anseswer. Can you please, tell me why it shuld be for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].lenght; j++?

Comment: @Nikoa `matrix.length` gives you number of rows, `matrix[0].length` gives you number of columns.

Comment: @ShanuGupta thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Matrix {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
int matrix[][] = new int[7][8];
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = i + 1 ;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        //Change this line,looking for this?
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j]*matrix[i][j] + "\t");
       //Describe your specific problem properly
    }
    System.out.println();
}}
```

Comment: I'm new her. Can u tell me how u should describe my problem properly? How u would describe my problem? Just to know for the next time..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Java.lang.Math.pow()** method. But since its only a sqaure function I dont see any harm in using  `matrix[i][j] = (i+1)*(i+1) ;` , inject this code at your 8th line.